# java.sql.SQLException: ORA-00934: group function is not allowed here oracle

Tags: java, oracle

in java code give me this exception

> java.sql.SQLException: ORA-00934: group function is not allowed here

when trying this query although
 when i run  this query in sql engine run fine without any exception

```
SELECT MAX(insert_date)
FROM SDP_SYNCH_REQUEST
HAVING ((sysdate - MAX(insert_date)) * 24 * 60) > 5
```

i don't know why

Comment: `SELECT MAX(insert_date) FROM ... WHERE (sysdate - insert_date) * 24 * 60 > 5`

Comment: i don't need to remove MAX function from inside where clause as i want to subtract the last record time from current time ?!

Comment: `Having` can be used when you `group by`...

Comment: Can you remove either the SQL Server or Oracle tag.  These are different products which often require different solutions.  I suspect you are using Oracle.  It is unusual to see HAVING without a GROUP BY.  Can you explain what you are trying to achieve?  If you could provide some sample records and the expected output that would help too.

Comment: @Valijon : the query run fine on the oracle DB engine without using group by

Comment: @destination-data : ok sorry for that

Comment: @destination-data : i need to check if there is delay in incoming requests by returning error code 500 when the delay in time for the last inserted record in database greater than 5 minutes ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do, you *validation* in `SELECT` and handle the cases appropriately.

```
SELECT 
  CASE WHEN ((SYSDATE - MAX(insert_date)) * 24 * 60) > 5
       THEN
            MAX(insert_date)
       ELSE
            NULL
  END as insert_date
FROM SDP_SYNCH_REQUEST
```

Or only if you consider, if it returns a row or not.

```
SELECT insert_date
FROM
( 
  SELECT MAX(insert_date) AS insert_date
  FROM SDP_SYNCH_REQUEST
) WHERE ((SYSDATE - insert_date) * 24 * 60) > 5
```

Comment: the second solution give me error > inconsistent Data type expected NUMBER got Date and the first solution i cannot understand , thank u for trying help